# Async pipe within ngIf directive

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

When using the `AsyncPipe` inside of an `*ngIf`, if the `Observable` connected to the `AsyncPipe` pushes its values before the `*ngIf` becomes true, the value returned from the `AsyncPipe` will be incorrect.

For example, let's say I have:

```
<div *ngIf="showPipe">
    <div *ngFor="let item of arrObs | async">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Then say events happen in this order:

1. `showPipe` is false
2. `arrObs` pushes [1,2,3]
3. `showPipe` is set to true

From what I've seen, the `*ngFor` will act as if `arrObs | async` returned null.

One solution to this problem is to use `[hidden]` instead, but there are a lot of benefits to `*ngIf`, like performance and making null handling easier.

What's the proper way to do this? Should I just not use an observable at all for displaying content? I had assumed that using an observable was the most Angular-y way of doing things.

Edit:
My observable is actually just a `new Subject()` which I call `next()` on.

Comment: I think it depends if arrObs is a "cold" obervable vs a "hot" observable. "hot" observables emits value only at precise times, and subscribers that listen _after_ this time don't observe anything until there is actually a new value emitted. A cold observable will re-emit its values if the subscription is done later, which I suspect that would be the case here. This is not tested in your setup, and just a thought / comment, not a definitive answer.

Comment: How is arrObs defined? Normally when you subscribe to a cold observable, it is executed every time, but if for example it's a Subject, it won't do that. You could change it to a BehaviorSubject/ReplaySubject, or pipe shareReplay(1) at the end.

Comment: can you show how is `arrObs` defined? Alternatively, could you build a [mcve] on StackBlitz?

Comment: @BartvandenBurg I edited my question to include my setup. Your guess was right that it was a Subject! I'll probably accept the answer that includes the ReplaySubject suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some ways you can solve this. I would suggest adding a `shareReplay` operator on your `Observable`:

```
readonly arrObs = this.someDataFromSomewhere().pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

<sub>if your `Observable` is actually a `Subject`, you can also change it to a `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`</sub>

This way you will always receive the most up to date data on subscription.

There are also ways to handle this in the template and still maintain the `*ngIf` benefits:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="arrObs | async as arr">
  <div *ngIf="showPipe">
    <div *ngFor="let item of arr">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Or if you don't want the `*ngIf` to wait for the observable

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ arr: arrObs | async } as data">
 <div *ngIf="showPipe">
   <div *ngFor="let item of data.arr">{{item}}</div>
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I didn't know about ReplaySubject, that solves my problem perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Surround your structure in an `ng-container` which contains the async pipe and stores the value in a variable using `as`. Also use the `ng-if` directive to load the container only after you get a value in that async pipe.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="( arrObs| async ) as array">
    <div *ngIf="showPipe">
        <div *ngFor="let item of array">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In NgRx 10 and above, you can use the `*ngrxLet` directive along with the `@ngrx/component` package ([documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let)).

Usage example:

```
<ng-container *ngrxLet="observableNumber$ as n">
    <app-number [number]="n">
    </app-number>
</ng-container>
```